# JTextField is under image when a new image is loaded

Tags: java, image, user-interface, jtextfield

Currently the problem I have is that whenever I load a new image that changes my JTextField setVisible to true it is staying behind the image and only appears if I highlight it with my mouse.

The only time it actually appears how I want it is the very first time I run the program, on the first image.

In my specific situation the problem is occurring when I go to "Enter Amount to Deposit/Withdraw:". It only works on the very first run the first time they go to enter their account number.

Also, anytime I am setting the visibility to true I am also setting the opaque to true as well.

This is what I would like it to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvUlJ.jpg

This is what it looks like when I go to a new Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX5BC.jpg

For reference here is all the code (warning: very messy):

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //jtf.setVisible(false);
        String str = "";

        if (screen == Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN) {
            screen = Screen.ENTER_ACC_SCREEN;
            numberString = "";
            jtf.setVisible(true);
            jtf.setOpaque(true);
            repaint();
        }
        if (screen == Screen.ENTER_ACC_SCREEN) {
            jtf.setVisible(true);
            jtf.setBounds(220, 350, 200, 35);
            jtf.setOpaque(true);
            if (e.getSource() == bp) {
                if (cData.customerList(numberString) != null) {
                    screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                    repaint();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
                    jop.showMessageDialog(panel1, "\tInvalid Account Number.\nNo such account exits.\nPlease Re-enter account number.\n");
                    numberString = "";
                }
            }
        }
        if (screen == Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS) {
            jtf.setVisible(false);
            if (e.getSource().equals(l1)) {
                screen = Screen.ACC_INFO_SCREEN;

                JTextField checkBal = new JTextField();
                JTextField saveBal = new JTextField();

                double temp = cData.checkBal(numberString);
                String check = String.valueOf(temp);
                panelMain.add(checkBal, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                checkBal.setText(check);
                checkBal.setEditable(false);
                checkBal.setVisible(true);
                checkBal.setFont(new Font("Arial",1,25));
                checkBal.setBounds(340, 125, 200, 25);

                double temp2 = cData.saveBal(numberString);
                String check2 = String.valueOf(temp2);
                panelMain.add(saveBal, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                saveBal.setText(check2);
                saveBal.setEditable(false);
                saveBal.setVisible(true);
                saveBal.setFont(new Font("Arial",1,25));
                saveBal.setBounds(340, 239, 200, 25);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource().equals(l2)) {
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource().equals(l3)) {
                screen = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN;
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource().equals(r1)) {
                screen = Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN;
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource().equals(r2)) {
                screen = Screen.DEPOSIT_SCREEN;
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource().equals(r3)) {
                screen = Screen.TRANSFER_SCREEN;
                repaint();
            }
        }
        if (screen == Screen.ACC_INFO_SCREEN) {
            if (e.getSource() == l3) {
                screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                repaint();
            }
        }
        if (screen == Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN_2) {
            if (e.getSource() == l3) {     
                screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                numberString = "";
                repaint();
            } 
        }
        if (screen == Screen.ENTER_ACC_SCREEN || screen == Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN || screen == Screen.DEPOSIT_SCREEN || screen == Screen.TRANSFER_SCREEN || screen == Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN_2 || screen == Screen.TRANSACTION) {
            jtf.setFont(new Font("Arial",1,25));
            jtf.setActionCommand("ENTER");
            jtf.addActionListener(this);
            jtf.setVisible(true);
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            if (screen == Screen.TRANSACTION) {
                if (e.getSource() == r1) {
                    screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                    numberString = "";
                    repaint();
                } else if (e.getSource()== r2) {
                    screen = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN;
                    numberString = "";
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            if (screen == screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN) {
                if (e.getSource() == l1) {
                    screen = Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN_2;

                    numberString = "";
                    jtf.setBounds(390, 90, 200, 50);
                    repaint();
                    jtf.setVisible(true);
                    jtf.setOpaque(true);
                    if (e.getSource() == bp) {
                        int wAmount = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
                        cData.subtractCheckBal(numberString, wAmount);
                        screen = Screen.TRANSACTION;
                        repaint();
                        if (e.getSource().equals(r1)) {
                            screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                            repaint();
                        } else if (e.getSource().equals(r2)) {
                            screen = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN;
                            repaint();
                        }
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == l2) {
                    screen = Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN_2;
                    repaint();
                    jtf.setVisible(true);
                    jtf.setOpaque(true);
                    numberString = "";
                    jtf.setBounds(390, 90, 200, 50);
                    if (e.getSource() == bp) {
                        int wAmount = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
                        cData.subtractSaveBal(numberString, wAmount);
                        screen = Screen.TRANSACTION;
                        repaint();
                        if (e.getSource().equals(r1)) {
                            screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                            repaint();
                        } else if (e.getSource().equals(r2)) {
                            screen = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN;
                            repaint();
                        }
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == l3) {
                    screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            if (screen == screen.DEPOSIT_SCREEN) {
                if (e.getSource() == l1) {
                    screen = Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN_2;
                    jtf.setVisible(true);
                    jtf.setOpaque(true);
                    numberString = "";
                    jtf.setBounds(390, 90, 200, 50);
                    repaint();
                    if (e.getSource() == bp) {
                        int dAmount = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
                        cData.addCheckBal(numberString, dAmount);
                        screen = Screen.TRANSACTION;
                        repaint();
                        if (e.getSource().equals(r1)) {
                            screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                            repaint();
                        } else if (e.getSource().equals(r2)) {
                            screen = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN;
                            repaint();
                        }
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == l2) {
                    screen = Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN_2;
                    repaint();
                    jtf.setVisible(true);
                    jtf.setOpaque(true);
                    jtf.setBounds(390, 90, 200, 50);
                    repaint();
                    if (e.getSource() == bp) {
                        int dAmount = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
                        cData.addSaveBal(numberString, dAmount);
                        screen = Screen.TRANSACTION;
                        repaint();
                        if (e.getSource().equals(r1)) {
                            screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                            repaint();
                        } else if (e.getSource().equals(r2)) {
                            screen = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN;
                            repaint();
                        }
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource().equals(l3)) {
                    screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
            if (screen == Screen.TRANSFER_SCREEN) {
                if (e.getSource() == l1) { // transfer from checking to savings
                    screen = Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN_2;
                    repaint();
                    jtf.setVisible(true);
                    jtf.setOpaque(true);
                    jtf.setBounds(390, 90, 200, 50);
                    if (e.getSource() == bp) {
                        int dAmount = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
                        cData.addSaveBal(numberString, dAmount);
                        cData.subtractCheckBal(numberString, dAmount);
                        screen = Screen.TRANSACTION;
                        repaint();
                        if (e.getSource().equals(r1)) { 
                            screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                            repaint();
                        } else if (e.getSource().equals(l2)) {
                            screen = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource() == l2) { // transfer from savings to checking
                    screen = Screen.WITHDRAW_SCREEN_2;
                    repaint();
                    jtf.setVisible(true);
                    //jtf.setbounds
                    int dAmount = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
                    cData.addCheckBal(numberString, dAmount);
                    cData.subtractSaveBal(numberString, dAmount);
                    screen = Screen.TRANSACTION;
                    repaint();
                    if (e.getSource().equals(r1)) {
                        screen = Screen.MAIN_BUTTONS;
                        repaint();
                    } else if (e.getSource().equals(l2)) {
                        screen = Screen.WELCOME_SCREEN;
                    }
                } else if (e.getSource().equals(l3)) {
                    screen = Screen.TRANSFER_SCREEN;
                    repaint();
                    jtf.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b1) {
                numberString += "1";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
                numberString += "2";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == b3) {
                numberString+= "3";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == b4) {
                numberString+= "4";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == b5) {
                numberString+= "5";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == b6) {
                numberString+= "6";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == b7) {
                numberString+= "7";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == b8) {
                numberString+= "8";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == b9) {
                numberString+= "9";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == b0) {
                numberString+= "0";
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == ba) { // clear button 
                // clear previous entry
                if (numberString.length() > 0) {
                    numberString = numberString.substring(0, numberString.length() - 1);
                }
                jtf.setText(numberString);
                repaint();
            }  
        }
```

Comment: can you give a sorce code or something? we can't guess what you did

Comment: Yeah, it's really messy though.

Comment: have you added the image before or after the `JTextField`?

Comment: Do you mean added to the panel?

Comment: yes, what did you added first, the `jtf`or the image?

Comment: Well, I just have all my Images in an enum and then the ImageIO in a try/catch and whenever I want to see the image I just set the current screen e.g screen = Screen.ENTER_ACC_SCREEN; As for the JTF I have it in a subpanel of a main panel.